# How can I send letter mail online?

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a webapp that will allow me to send someone a physical letter from a PDF file on my computer?

They would print the file I upload, and send the letter to the address specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Snailmailme](http://www.snailmailme.com/index.php) is a service that does what you are looking for, but it's not free.

> Snailmailme.com™ is a fun and unique way to stay in touch with your friends and loved-ones using letter mail. In a few simple steps you can create a fully customized letter or postcard that we will physically print and deliver for you to virtually any serviceable mailing address in the world!

[click2mail](https://click2mail.com/email-to-mail) is another one.
[snailmailr](http://snailmailr.com/) is yet another one.